# Arreglos en java ordenar de manera aleatoria

Tags: java, array, random

El problema es el siguiente:
**Pedir 10 números enteros ordenados crecientemente, y realizar una operación para desordenarlos.**

Yo he hecho un código pero las posiciones del array son siempre el mismo lo que yo quiero es que las posiciones del array sean aleatorias .

```
package array5;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Array5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sn=new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean creciente=true;
   int array[]=new int[10];

  do{ 
for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
      System.out.println("digite un numero");   
      array[i]=sn.nextInt();
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
     if(array[i]<array[i+1]){
       creciente =true;  
     }
     if(array[i]>array[i+1]){
         creciente=false;
         break;
     }
    }
    if(creciente==false){
        System.out.println("\nEl arreglo no esta ordenado en fornma creciente,vuelva a digitar ");
        
    }
    
  }while(creciente==false); 
 
  System.out.println("Los numero en desorden:");         
   System.out.println(array[5]);
   System.out.println(array[2]);     
   System.out.println(array[0]);
   System.out.println(array[9]);
   System.out.println(array[3]);
   System.out.println(array[1]);
   System.out.println(array[4]);
   System.out.println(array[8]);
   System.out.println(array[7]);
   System.out.println(array[6]);
    }
    
}
```

Al final de este código yo le he asignado un orden especifico para imprimir los datos lo que yo quiero es que se impriman de manera aleatoria siempre.
Me gustaria saber si hay alguna forma de hacerlo.

```
introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: Quizás esto te pueda ayudar [Collections#shuffle(List)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List))

Answer (score 1):

Una opción es usar el barajamiento o barajado de [Fisher-Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle), el cual es un algoritmo para generar permutaciones aleatorias de elementos de una lista o secuencia finita. (Traducción propia):

> El algoritmo coloca efectivamente todos los elementos en un sombrero; determina continuamente el siguiente elemento escogiendo aleatoriamente un elemento del sombrero, hasta que no queden elementos en el sombrero.

Usando este algoritmo puedes *desordenar* una lista o arreglo de elementos de tal forma que las posiciones de los mismos se garantizan lo suficientemente aleatorias
como lo permita el sistema.

Por ejemplo:

```java
public class shuffle {
  /* Función de barajamiento usando el algoritmo Fisher Yates
  *  Se recibe un arreglo de enteros (ordenado o no) y se aplica
  *  el algoritmo de Fisher - Yates
  *
  *  Se devuelve un arreglo de enteros desordenado aleatoriamente
  */
  private static int[] fisher_yates(int[] arreglo) {
    // recorremos todo el arreglo
    for(int i = arreglo.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      // calculamos un índice aleatorio dentro del rango permitido
      int shuffled_index = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      //guardamos el elemento que estamos iterando
      int tmp = arreglo[i];
      // asignamos el elemento aleatorio al índice iterado
      arreglo[i] = arreglo[shuffled_index];
      // asignamos el elemento iterado al índice aleatorio
      arreglo[shuffled_index] = tmp;
    }
    return arreglo;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] arreglo = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    //Fisher-Yates shuffle:
    int[] shuffled = fisher_yates(arreglo);
    for (int i = 0, len = shuffled.length; i < len; i++) {
      System.out.println(shuffled[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Este código lo puedes adaptar de acuerdo a tus necesidades, pero siendo un algoritmo ya probado, te garantiza que siempre obtendrás elementos desordenados aleatoriamente.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Puede declarar una lista para almacenar numeros random en el rango del tamaño de su array

```
List<Integer> pos = new List<Integer>();
int c = 0;
while(c<array.length()){
          int x = (int) (Math.random()*10);
          if(!pos.contains(x)){
              pos.add(x);
               c++;
     }
}
```

Y luego imprimir esa lista, perdone si no funciona tal cual, estoy desde el cel jajaja

Answer (score 0):

He metido los numero directamente en la variable pero puedes adaptar tu metodo
La solucion que aplico es poco eficiente pero te servira
una vez tienes el array lo clonas para no perderlo he añadido un metodo que le pasas el array y un indice y te retorna el array son el numero del indice luego he bucado en internet como generar numeros aleatorios con tamaño de tal forma que lo que hace el codigo es

1. Clona el array
2. Obtiene un numero aleatorio con el tamaño del array como maximo
3. Elimina el elemento del array (lo imprimo por pantalla)
4. Retorno el nuevo array
5. Repito los puntos 2,3,4 hasta quedarme sin elementos

***añadir -->*** import java.util.*;

```
public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    int array[] = {
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7
    };
    int[] copiedArray = Arrays.copyOf(array, array.length);

    for (int x = 0; x < copiedArray.length; x++) {
        System.out.print(copiedArray[x]);
    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("impresion aleactoria");
    Random rand = new Random();
    while (copiedArray.length > 0) {
        int rand_int1 = rand.nextInt(copiedArray.length);
        System.out.print(copiedArray[rand_int1]);
        copiedArray = removeTheElement(copiedArray, rand_int1);

    }
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("tamaño array final" + copiedArray.length);


}
public static int[] removeTheElement(int[] arr,
    int index) {

    // If the array is empty 
    // or the index is not in array range 
    // return the original array 
    if (arr == null ||
        index < 0 ||
        index >= arr.length) {

        return arr;
    }

    // Create another array of size one less 
    int[] anotherArray = new int[arr.length - 1];

    // Copy the elements except the index 
    // from original array to the other array 
    for (int i = 0, k = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

        // if the index is 
        // the removal element index 
        if (i == index) {
            continue;
        }

        // if the index is not 
        // the removal element index 
        anotherArray[k++] = arr[i];
    }

    // return the resultant array 
    return anotherArray;
}
}
```