# Sacar un número aleatorio de un array sin que se repita

Tags: java

Tengo este código, un bingo simple, muy de principiante, por eso me gustaria sacar una bola en cada iteracion del bucle while sin que se repita, sin usar arrays list ni hash set ni cosas más avanzadas, puro if, for etc; Justo después del punto donde empieza el if con el eInicial=1, justo ahí podeis ver como se crea una bola aleatoria, pero se repiten números en cada iteración. He probado diferentes métodos pero no he conseguido que funcione bien.

Gracias de antemano.

os dejo el código por aqui

```
package bingo;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class BingoPruebas {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] numeros = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,
            19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36,
            37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54,
            55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72,
            73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90};
    
    int longitudValores=90;
    int filas = 3;
    int columnas = 9;
    int [][] carton = new int [filas][columnas];
    int bolas = 0;
    int intentos=0;
    
    System.out.println("Bienvenido al Bingo");
    System.out.println("Este es tu carton:");
    
    for (int i=0;i<filas;i++) {
        System.out.println(" ");
        for(int j=0;j<columnas;j++) {
            Random random = new Random();
            int posicion=random.nextInt(0,longitudValores);
            carton[i][j]=numeros[posicion];
            numeros[posicion]=numeros[longitudValores-1];
            longitudValores--;
            System.out.print(carton[i][j]+" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
    System.out.println(" ");
    
    while(intentos<90) {
        
        int eInicial;
        System.out.println("¿Desea sacar una bola? SI(1)/NO(2)");
            
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        eInicial=sc.nextInt();

        if (eInicial==1) {
            
            System.out.println("");
        
            Random bola = new Random();
            bolas = bola.nextInt(numeros.length);
            System.out.println("Ha salido la bola número: "+ bolas);
            
            for(int i=0; i <carton.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(" ");
                for(int j=0;j<carton[i].length;j++) {
                    System.out.print(carton[i][j]+" ");
                    }
            }
        
            System.out.println(" ");
            System.out.println(" ");
            
            for (int i=0; i <carton.length; i++) {
                for (int j=0;j<carton[i].length;j++) {
                    if(carton[i][j] == bolas) {
                        carton[i][j]=-1;    
                    }
                }
            }
            
            boolean hasGanado = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
                    if (carton[i][j] != -1) {
                        hasGanado = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (hasGanado) {
                System.out.println("!Bingo, has ganado!");
                break;
            }
        }
        
        else if (eInicial==2) {
            System.out.println("¡Hasta pronto!");
            break;
            }
        
        else {
            System.out.println("Por favor, indique si o no con un número válido");
        }
        
        intentos++;
        
    }
    if(intentos>=90) {
    System.out.println("Te has quedado sin intentos, has perdido");
    }
}}
```

Gracias de antemano

Al final lo saqué así

```
Random b= new Random(); 
int pos2=b.nextInt(longitudValores2);
bola=BolasN[pos2]; 
BolasN[pos2]=BolasN[longitudValores2-1];
longitudValores2--;
System.out.print("Ha salido la bola número: "+bola);
```

En cada iteración mueves el número a la úiltima posición y eliminas esa posición, por lo que ya no saldría repetido.

Comment: Prueba guardando en en alguna parte las bolas que van saliendo para llevar el control. Al pedir una nueva bola la buscas ahí, si existe sigues sacando hasta que sea diferente.

Comment: Relacionado: [Arreglos en java ordenar de manera aleatoria](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/369017/arreglos-en-java-ordenar-de-manera-aleatoria/369059#369059)

Comment: Al final lo saqué así Random b= new Random();
    int pos2=b.nextInt(longitudValores2);
    bola=BolasN[pos2];
    BolasN[pos2]=BolasN[longitudValores2-1];
    longitudValores2--;          
    System.out.print("Ha salido la bola número: "+bola);               En cada iteración mueves el número a la úiltima posición y eliminas esa posición, por lo que ya no saldría repetido.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La forma más sencilla de hacerlo es desordenar la lista y luego sacar los valores en el orden que hayan quedado.

Puedes usar el [algoritmo de Fisher-Yates](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Fisher-Yates) para desordenar la lista.

Por ejemplo, el siguiente método, recibe una lista y la desordena:

```java
private static int[] fisher_yates(int[] arreglo) {
  // recorremos todo el arreglo
  for(int i = arreglo.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    // calculamos un índice aleatorio dentro del rango permitido
    int shuffled_index = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    //guardamos el elemento que estamos iterando
    int tmp = arreglo[i];
    // asignamos el elemento aleatorio al índice iterado
    arreglo[i] = arreglo[shuffled_index];
    // asignamos el elemento iterado al índice aleatorio
    arreglo[shuffled_index] = tmp;
  }
  return arreglo;
}
```

De esta manera, no tienes que generar valores aleatorios cada vez, simplemente desordenas de forma aleatoria el Array original y luego lo recorres completo, cada salida será diferente y aleatoria, debido al desordenamiento inicial.

Puedes compilar este ejemplo para que veas que en cada corrida se muestran los primeros 10 elementos del Array y siempre serán distintos y estarán desordenados.

```java
public class bingo {
  private static int[] fisher_yates(int[] arreglo) {
    // recorremos todo el arreglo
    for(int i = arreglo.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      // calculamos un índice aleatorio dentro del rango permitido
      int shuffled_index = (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
      //guardamos el elemento que estamos iterando
      int tmp = arreglo[i];
      // asignamos el elemento aleatorio al índice iterado
      arreglo[i] = arreglo[shuffled_index];
      // asignamos el elemento iterado al índice aleatorio
      arreglo[shuffled_index] = tmp;
    }
    return arreglo;
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] numeros = new int[90];
    for(int i = 0; i < 90; ++i) {
      numeros[i] = i + 1;
    }
    int [] numeros_desordenados = fisher_yates(numeros);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      System.out.println("Ha salido:" + numeros_desordenados[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Para el caso de tu juego, no necesitas usar un bucle `while`, simplemente recorrer el Array de valores desordenados, y en cada iteración verificar si el valor se encuentra en el cartón del jugador.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver el problema.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías simplemente generar números aleatorios hasta que obtengas uno que no salió, pero eso resulta en iteraciones innecesarias.

Puedes usar un arreglo para registrar las bolas que salieron y un entero que lleve la cuenta de las restantes.

Así:

```
static int cantidadBolasRestantes = numeros.length;
static bool[] bolasRestantes = new bool[cantidadBolasRestantes];
```

A cada elemento del arreglo `numeros` le corresponde un `boolean` en la misma posición del arreglo `bolasRestantes`.

Entonces, para obtener una bola generas un número aleatorio entre 0 y la cantidad de bolas restantes. Llámale **n**. Luego empleas un ciclo para buscar la **n**-sima bola disponible.

Así:

```
static int posicionBolaAleatoria(){
    int n = random.nextInt(cantidadBolasRestantes);
    int i, j = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < bolasRestantes.length; i++){
        if (bolasRestantes[i])
            j++;
    
        if (bolasRestantes[i] && j == n)
            return i;
    }

    // No sé encontró 
    return -1;
}

static int bolaAleatoria(){
    int posicion = posicionBolaAleatoria();
    bolasRestantes[posicion] = false;
    cantidadBolasRestantes--;
    return = numeros[posicion];
}
```

Solo falta inicializar todos los elementos del arreglo en `true` antes de empezar.

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##tVfLbuM2FN3rK26yGMi14kTySxlFLRq06GTRaTEpugm8oG06oUcmXUn2tA38MbPsurtuCjQflh7qFevhRwNUhmGDPOfy8tx7yas5W7Oz@fTj87NYLFUY0xwDnVUsgs4XnmEsV@NATGgSsCii75mQ9GgYhCeKWYwJIWO6G5FcLXioIvLp0bbIsahrUc@ivkUDi4YWuRZdWmRf4It5GwAbCBsQGxgbIBso27US2/ljg@OA42ib4DjgOOA44DjgOOA4MO0A1wWuC1xXLw5cF7gucN1B2WYXnC44XXB64PTA6YHT0x6D0wOnB9s94HrA9YDrA9cHrg9cH7h@r2yzD04fnD44fXD64AzAGYAzAGcAzgC2B1oP4AbADYAbADcEbgjc0CnbHIIzBGcIzlCLCM4QnCE4LjguOC5su8C5wLnAucC5Wm3gXOAuLzZeYrQasUDJexGvpj@zQIU88i8vvCpkJhByxLNbm5moYLWQyeSlV88FZMOEhbGSmJf8UzqaWBvd5dRRjTdW6XJ1R/DlMlaRj6maK0zGYsqm15r9gWMGYG0my8dOwOV9/FCyOVYq4EzCzXGNBXfz6WbTo7IPH5icqgWF6U9qIB0zWxkyK6CMsFZiSguUkXkbh0LewwsW3kctVFURJ/0IKSaCBeJ3FmpL@XDx5/a3KOaLjlrFnSXsxIE0T68Fl2suxVQRC@ga1tXpFreJ8i2GCFuPV1nM3p42rTZTIZlJLBAEcZUE0xPtdu72viVo22JmLLE1h635VZ4R3rxuLhUipqWKoIaSfqpzR/Jf4xsZm5Usrqyjn3RTd2J0Nx/5WU7c5eZGdXwNUpAqa53ZDewq5qwOqSpkbnvYrou1Mer/Dqq8F/CCQoZLHlI0yRI3GzAzupBNqfDpQQTczGvy6vKiGjSjGj1@k@aydzBV/vn7Gx5xRhGDKrSSLKnQr@j2xrRb5@9/MJ3WaUOQSwP5an40KfKkuvPEsxmZBda3m1LvYPC0z1WHaqT8YNO/X@NkiVUomNnyjrL@TosR6IoOUjFIPv2lE/ItnbZT04cE2S45Xb4k6CpNuvxwJNFcekdX9I7KzjM7X2e@e5nXlEZzmTSPGK/e19HAJtHplaoX1NcpKWYl7cj3s1TZw6mdlme217it3ZIfE4gdJZJcufTAou@YZMh2n@Jwxb09miatglY1bVSOlDNlzcEq7h06KCaV1Tzx6cw@JOX2VmYsiLi3Fz4OOfvo/Q9aa@8LX/5LkZ8k/YOlN0L3CftkVwHucH5jHFmPHPJUzmOnydXGK@PzO4bWipahwn3U6OJR7tUdOm79H5FaM7ZWoYW7bip@WXGKBCmSChkmcYflBzatnz7rg3z3Bd90eSaXbLu944p54aLic/SXfvlObvL6J57EFd5OdYpGeKvL6WnElzycVpxNF9uU2t@kmy21qo/GvlItN9ylk9Co3ZkFDnVXOhA2tdeAvF27Lt@xj8Z2H6LfRyoNZHOPn3fuOVFY2cFR2dtR@3qsdR21zbVqmTbfDvlhA/TmjfYQXVzdVMjjVYjwbgey@Ht@Tu8R/qc/iEukaxw@/fmyXMbEPbBD9fE@tfOQQKQd0XnxqLKhovmun53NAdtutDOvd/T62ISxeX62Kf04/wI).

Por cierto, no debes crear una instancia nueva del Scanner en cada iteración porque obtendrás un error. Tampoco necesitas crear una instancia nueva de `Random` cada vez que quieres generar un número aleatorio.